# Who is this DC comic book character?

Tags: dc, character-identification

[image]
He’s in an action splash panel with Batman, Superman, and Wonder Woman (on a piece of wall art I received as a gift), but I’ve never seen him before.[image]

Comment: Can you post the entire wall art?

Comment: I added a picture of the entire wall art

Comment: Posting the whole thing made it searchable on google

Answer (score 6):

This is [Mister 08](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Terrence_Sloan_(Earth_2)) (AKA Terry Sloan AKA Terrence Sloan AKA Overwatch-One)

You can see the [cover art](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/earth-2-2012/earth-2-0) that they've used below.

[image]